# Identify installed software packages on Centos machine

Tags: linux, centos, rpm

I am trying to identify the installed software on Centos servers, until now I 'came up' with the following two basic solutions

1. Parse the file system for executables and libs
2. Run something like `rpm -qa`

The first one is time consuming, while the second does not apply to all my cases. For example I want to 'search' for packages even if the server is not running and I can access only its file system as a remote Volume, a Snapshot or an Image.

What I am thinking is to try and parse the same database / files that `rpm -qa` reads the data from.

After running `strace -o /tmp/rpm-strace.out rpm -qa` I found (without being sure) that `/var/lib/rpm/Packages` and `/var/lib/rpm/Names` are some possible locations for that 'database' but I can not parse any of those 2 files.

Does anyone know how to parse these files? Is there any alternative to achieve what I want?

**Note:** The whole idea is feasible under Ubuntu as [this 'Unix & Linux'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/200171/109640) question describes.

**Disclaimer:** This question may be more suitable for serverfault site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to use `rpm` to parse the rpm database.  If you have access to the filesystem, you could simply use `chroot` to run `rpm` inside the appropriate root context:

```
chroot /my/server/filesystem rpm -qa
```

Those files are various sorts of BerkeleyDB database files.  Assuming that your runtime environment has the same version of BerkeleyDB available, you can use something like Python's `bsddb` module to read them:

```
>>> import bsddb
>>> name = bsddb.btopen('/var/lib/rpm/Name')
>>> for pkg in name.keys():
...   print pkg
...
GConf2
GeoIP
GeoIP-GeoLite-data
GeoIP-GeoLite-data-extra
GitPython
GraphicsMagick
[...]
```

But this is a terrible idea and you shouldn't do it, because who knows if the `Name` database has exactly what you're looking for?  Maybe it includes deleted packages that are somehow marked deleted, so `rpm -qa` would ignore them.  You would probably need to look at the rpm sources to figure out exactly how things are stored.

Comment: As I said I am assuming that the aforementioned files store the information I want. So you are right, this is a terrible idea, but I have to try it and see if works. Nevertheless I think `chroot /my/server/filesystem rpm -qa` is the way to go.

Comment: "rpm -qa --root /my/server/filesystem" works similary.

Answer (score 1):

my (fedora) `rpm` command accepts a `--dbpath` option to specify a different
directory with the database. There is also a `rpm-python` package to manipulate the database from python.

Comment: For some reason this does not work in my Centos Machine. I also trying the `--root` as @msuchy suggest but still the result is the same.